# How to get all the column names of a class in Android parse.com Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

I want to get all the column values for a single row in parse.com without using `parseObject.get(String key)` for each key as I have many. Is there a way to get all the column names as an array? Or perhaps iterate over all the columns for a single row to get all the data from that row?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of the following 
 and has already been answered.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33246163/java-parse-iterate-over-parseobject-fields

Comment: Thank you that worked great.